# performKeyEquivalent on active application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos-carbon

In carbon/cocoa, is it possible to send something like performKeyEquivalent to the current key window? I want to send a key event to whatever application the user has active.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can post events using `CGEventPost`.